# List failed login attempts on Yosemite

Tags: macos, security, login, logs

I want to see if somebody has tried to log in on my computer, which is running Yosemite. I am primarily interested in tracking ssh log in attempts, as well as tracking people physically typing passwords on my keyboard to try to log in.

**Closely related**

[List failed login attempts on Mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/120668/37955)

Answer (score 2):

sshd logging is determined in `/etc/asl/com.openssh.sshd`.

In short, you need to touch a file and then send syslogd a HUP signal:
`touch /var/run/com.openssh.sshd-asl-enabled`
`kill -HUP $(ps -ef | grep [s]yslogd | awk '{print $2}')`

After that, you will find the logs in `/var/log/sshd.log`

Answer (score 0):

*This answer is based on [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/120670/37955), but that answer does not list ssh attempts on Yosemite*

Here is a start

```
grep "authentication error for" /private/var/log/system.log
```

This probably lists all failed login attempts via ssh. The answer in the linked answer still works; you can use

```
grep "Failed to authenticate user" /private/var/log/system.log
```

to see failed local login attempts. This does not include login attempts from a terminal window. It does include failed attempts to "switch user".